# Expected value of a single variable Function

Tags: probability, expected-value

$\displaystyle{ f_x(x) = 6x^5 \text{ for } 0 < x <1}$

A.) Find $\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]$

B.) Find $P\bigl[1/3 \le X \le 2/3\bigr]$

Comment: Do you know how to find the expected value of a continuous distribution?

Comment: E[X]=Integral (x*6x^5) form 0-1 
that's how I approached it but not so sure.

Comment: Yes! That is correct. Now just follow through with the integration: $$\int_0^1 6x^6 \, dx$$

Comment: Thanks! A silly question I know but I got confused among the basic concepts, thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basic probability theory.

A. $E(X)=\int_0^1xf_X(x)dx=\frac{6}{7}$.

B. $P(1/3\le X \le 2/3)=\int_{1/3}^{2/3}f_X(x)dx=(2/3)^6-(1/3)^6$